# Python Flask with Waitress WSGI not working with Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn, waitress

I was learning about building web apps and putting them on Heroku.

I made a basic HTML website, which runs perfectly on the local server but it's showing "Application Error " on Heroku. I was initially using gunicorn (which was giving me an H10 error), then I later learnt that gunicorn was incompatible with Windows so I switched to Waitress WSGI. This time I am getting an H14 error code.

I tried `heroku ps:scale web=1`

and I am getting this error :
`Scaling dynos... ! !    Couldn't find that process type (web).`

I tried almost everything that's there on the internet, but sadly I am not able to get past the error and host my website. It's really frustrating.

This is my current Procfile: `waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 website.wsgi:app`

I have also tried `waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 website.py:app`, the errors were indistinguishable :(

This is my Heroku log output :-

`2020-07-06T08:08:03.848586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=brohan-wsite.herokuapp.com request_id=72a95aa5-8d84-486f-b036-dc738d9cc62c fwd="106.215.63.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need something like:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT website:app
```

Heroku defines the port dynamically, so hardcoding port 8000 won't work.

Comment: Hey, it worked ! Thanks. Although initally it was giving me a "no dyno"  error, but I then I used heroku ps:scale web=1. and it worked :)